Javascript works on second click but not the first
By Default the textarea = 'Test', If I change to 'Test1' and click on the "Send Email To Selected Merchants" the first time.. It still passes 'Test' in the out div, but then when I click on 'No' on the confirm box... and click on "Send Email To Selected Merchants" second time it passes 'Test1' correctly.


var confirmed = false;

function confirmfinish() {
  if (!confirmed) {

    var content = document.getElementById('query').value;
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = content;
    document.getElementById('out').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('confirmationDiv').style.display = 'block';
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;

  }
}
<div id="confirmationDiv" class="confirmationDiv">
  <table class="minimalistBlack">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Are you sure all the below information is correct?</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="white">
          <div id="out" style="display:none;">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit3" value="Yes" onclick="confirmed = true; document.getElementById('form').submit();">
            <input type="button" value="No" onclick="document.getElementById('confirmationDiv').style.display='none'; return false;">
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  <form name="form" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return (ValidateForm(this,'enquiry') && confirmfinish() && ShowLoading())">
    <textarea style="height:700px;" name="query" cols="170" rows="60" id="query">Test</textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit3" value="Send Email To Selected Merchants"></td>
  </form>




You could turn this into a runnable stack snippet.

The code shown is referencing functions which don't exist and is not preventing the form from posting.  Can you update this to a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem you are trying to describe?

I do have have javascript function checks which i left out of the code

I made a snippet. Please [edit] and make it a [mcve] using VALID HTML. I strongly suggest you do NOT use onclick of a submit button but instead use the submit event of the form. There is no reason to have a submit button ouyside the form which can wrap the div or even use the form attribute

sorry i figured it would.... it as to do with the
<!--<script type="text/javascript">
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
new nicEditor({maxHeight : 375}).panelInstance('content');
});


in my code when i take the textarea out of that code it works
The first thing to do is stop using legacy onXyz HTML event attributes and instead use .addEventListener().
